# ASP.NET - Different behavior of nullable parameter binding in Web API and MVC controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, binding, asp.net-web-api2, nullable

Recently I realized that there is a difference between nullable type parameter binding by Web API and MVC.

1. The following URI `GET http://localhost/api/test` does not invoke
   the below Web API action method but `GET http://localhost/api/test/1` does.

   ```
   public class TestController : ApiController {
       public string Get(int? id) {
           return "sampleApp";
       }
   }
   ```

   and returns the below error

> ```
> <Error> 
>    <Message> 
>      No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/test'. 
>    </Message>
>    <MessageDetail> 
>      No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the request. 
>    </MessageDetail> 
> </Error>
> ```

2. But both the `GET http://localhost/test/Get (with id = null)` and `GET http://localhost/test/Get/1 (with id = 1)`  does invoke the below MVC action method and displays the view.

   ```
   public class TestController : Controller {
     public ActionResult Get(int? id) {
       ViewBag.Message = "Your app page.";
       return View();
     }
   }
   ```

I have explored on [MVC routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd410269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and learned that a nullable type parameter will be treated as an optional parameter in MVC and hence it will not be considered in the binding process.

But the same does not holds true for Web API which in turn needs an [explicit setup for optional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional).

Is there any reason for this different behavior between Web API and MVC for nullable type parameter binding.

Comment: Could you add attribute route `[Route("api/test/{id:int?}")]`to Web API action method, and see it makes any different?

Comment: @Win I'm already aware of specifying an optional parameter on the Web API action and have mentioned the same (`explicit setup`) in the question. But rather I'm looking for the reason behind the different behavior of a nullable parameter binding process!

Comment: Well, the behavior is not surprising since ASP.Net MVC 5 and Web API 2 use separate routing engine. It should not be issue in ASP.Net Core.

Comment: Yes of course. But I'm wondering why do they differ in binding a nullable type parameter!